# How to add image when img tag is less than 100 from top using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I want to add an image when the user scrolling down and mdl-grid is less than 100 from top.

Here is my html

```
<div class="mdl-grid  mdl-shadow--2dp" style="margin-top:4px;">
    <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--3-col-desktop mdl-cell--3-col-tablet mdl-cell--1-col-phone div-mobile">
        <div class="image-div" style="height:200px;width:200px;">
            <img class="image-tag" src="" style="height:200px;width:98px;" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Jquery

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    $('.mdl-grid').each(function () {
        var offsetTopPosition = $(this).offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();
        if (offsetTopPosition < 100) {
            $(this).find('img').attr('src', '/rec.jpeg');
        }
    });
});
</div>
```

Comment: So what's wrong with your code?

Comment: @Justinas it's not set the image when I scroll down

Comment: I think @Justinas was looking for more detail - do you see any errors in the console; if you put logging statements in the function, can you confirm your `offsetTopPosition` is being calculated as you expect, that you ever get into your `if()` condition, etc?

Comment: It work http://jsfiddle.net/mroj1ud5/

Comment: @Mohammad Sorry for delay. I saw that fiddle it is working there. But in mine it is not working

Comment: Check that console has any error