# Why window.scroll is not firing using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to image src when scrolling down.  Actually [this is my question before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53243211/how-to-add-image-when-img-tag-is-less-than-100-from-top-using-jquery?noredirect=1#comment93378817_53243211). But suggesting answer is right.

But when I try to alert something on **window.scroll**. I did not get any alert

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $(window).scroll(function () {
            if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
                alert("END!");
    }
});
```

Even i tried outside the document like below

```
{
    ViewBag.Title = "Mobile";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<head>
<script src="~/scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/scripts/Mobile/mobile.js"></script>

    <script>
    $(window).scroll(function () {
            alert("END!");     // also this one is not firing
    });

</script>
</head>
```

**My target is set an image src when it reach 100 from top scroll**

**update**

I tried below one also, but not getting alert

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() < 100) {
                alert("success");

            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

> 1. I am using Asp.net MVC Framework
> 2. I have `_Layout.cshtml` this is the file it has jquery link,
> 3. I have view page `mobile.cshtml`. whatever I wrote the code inside the `mobile.cshtml`, it will render inside the `_Layout.cshtml` file
> 4. I gave mobile.js file script link inside `mobile.cshtml`

Comment: Your first code snippet has syntax errors. Your final code works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/dry1Lw02/

Answer (score 0):

```
(function(){
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(this).scrollTop()>=100){
        // change image source
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I tried your code inside `$(documnet).ready(function(){})` not working brother

Comment: I found something, when i do `alert('test')` inside the (function(){ alert('test') //not working

Comment: I think you forgot to call your IIFE.

Comment: @Jacques what is **IIFE**?

Comment: Immediately Invoked Function Expression....the (function(){  })() part.

Comment: the missing part @Jacques was referring to was the () at the end...thats what actually invokes it

Comment: (Just to be clear, I was responder to the answerer.) IIFE stands for `immediately invoked function expression ` the `(function(){}) ` would be an IIFE if he added () to the end like this: `(function() {})()` basically, it’s a function that is called immediately after being defined.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your scroll function isn't firing is because you have to wait on the document ready event to be triggered before you wire it up.  This code works perfectly fine and alert is displayed:  (saw in your comment you tried it, but you have a misspelling in document...not sure if a typo).

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $(window).scroll(function () {
            if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
                alert("END!");
            }
        })
    });  //These are what you are missing above.
```

Comment: no brother. I misspelled on my comments. But in my code it is correct

Comment: then you have a separate issue and you will have to provide more details.  I tested this code and it works....it fires numerous alerts but it does work.   if you add an alert before wiring up the scroll does it fire?  ie...is jquery loading properly?

Comment: my jquery is running properly, otherwise, it will show error on console. when i do alert at first line of my js file, i got the alert message. I am not getting alert only when i do alert inside `window.scroll` function. I don't know why

Comment: The issue you have above is that you are missing a closing } and ) from your code.   I will update answer to reflect.

Comment: If the code in your post isn't what you are actually running, then we aren't going to be able to reliably help you as we are chasing a moving target.  If you copy/paste what I have above, does it still not fire?